# Употребление слова "хороводится"

Tags: семантика

Можно ли употребить слово "хороводится" в значении - нянчится, возится, присматривает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В словаре Ожегова (и других) такое значение имеется:
[хорово́диться](http://endic.ru/ozhegov/Horovoditsja-38384.html) — несов., **с кем-чем** (прост, неодобр.). То же, что возиться.

*В пятом классе она **хороводилась с малышами** с улицы, привязалась к Борьке Капелюхину, вместе со всем классом шефствовала над группой детдомовцев, потом в школе работала с октябрятами и вот снова в вожатые* (А. И. Мусатов. Клава Назарова).

― Говорят, и дела забросил, совсем в лавке не бывает, приказчики верховодят, как хотят. Только и утехи: **с голубями хороводится**. [С. И. Гусев-Оренбургский. Вселенская (1915) // «Пробуждение», №24, 1915, 1914]

Answer (score 2):

В словаре есть такое значение (хотя на практике чаще используется вариант "водить компанию с кем-то"):

ХОРОВОДИТЬСЯ,  нсв. **Разг.-сниж.** 1. Водить хороводы; 2. с кем-чем. **Иметь дело, обычно длительное, хлопотное с кем-, чем-л.**; возиться. **Х. с детьми, с молодняком.** Х. с сеном, огородом. Х. с организацией кооператива. 3. с кем. Водить компанию, знакомство Х. с бригадиром, с местным начальством. Х. с уголовниками. Х. с Клавкой.

Пример:

Дожди каждый день льют. Две недели с сеном хороводимся — совсем потемнело.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128758/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon---).

Answer (score 1):

Согласен что это уж очень малоупотребляемо,так же например слово ДЛЯТЬСЯ.Даже трудно теперь и понять без фразы целиком. Напр., в одном произведении:- -... где дляется грек Копродонис?
Или еще более устаревшее о реформах Христианства  времен патриарха Никона -- :"...пытался изловить всех вскую длявшихся.....#Егору Салькову: ....сейчас время появиться....,расхлебаю, тут в конторке, по работе и напишу о (...вскую дляется...; дляшися и т.п.)  с указанием откуда цитаты и примеры...у Ожегова такого нет уж точьно :)  Ну типа как в песне :- "Ненадо УПЯЧИТЬСЯ вся
жисть впереди(два раза)
......"

Comment: Да, Клава Назарова – это 1958 год.  А примеры  из словарей вообще из прошлого века:  «Дожди почесть каждый день льют. Две недели с сеном хороводимся – совсем потемнело». Салтыков-Щедрин, Пошехонская старина. «Пока ты тут хороводился со своей свадьбой, Половодов выхлопотал себе назначение». Мамин-Сибиряк, Приваловские миллионы.

Comment: user199525, а что это значит — «дляться»?

Comment: А вот пример из перевода на русский"Последнее воплощение Вотрена"о.Бальзака :— Ну, так и быть! Я хотел бы деньги отдать Гоноре, — отвечал Чистюлька жалобным голосом.
— Вот оно что!.. Ты живешь с вдовой Моисея, того самого еврея, что хороводился с южными Тряпичниками? — спросил Жак Коллен.
Подобно великим полководцам, Обмани‑Смерть превосходно знал личный состав всех шаек.